# Making HTTPS requests within a Docker image behind a Zscaler firewall

Tags: r, docker, ssl, openssl, zscaler

I'm interested in running a simple image like this behind a corporate Zscaler firewall:

```
FROM rocker/r-base
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libssl-dev
CMD Rscript -e "install.packages('beepr')"
```

Building the image with `docker build -t test .` fails with errors like this:

```
Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: ]
```

I've tried some of the solutions from [here](https://community.zscaler.com/t/installing-tls-ssl-root-certificates-to-non-standard-environments/7261#heading--docker) but they don't work. For example:

```
FROM rocker/r-base

# Add local certificate to Docker
ADD ./zscaler.cer /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/zscaler.crt

# Move the certificate to the cert dir of openssl and update certificates
RUN CERT_DIR=$(openssl version -d | cut -f2 -d \")/certs ; cp /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/zscaler.crt $CERT_DIR ; update-ca-certificates

# Try making https requests
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libssl-dev
CMD Rscript -e "install.packages('beepr')"
```

Same errors persist with `docker build -t test .`. I've read some possible solutions online but all of them continually fail either for `apt-get` or for installing packages with `R`. Is there anyone who has experienced this and found a fix?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the current advice is slightly wrong. The certificate should not go in `/etc/ssl/certs/` (which is the result of `CERT_DIR=$(openssl version -d | cut -f2 -d \")/certs`) but rather on `CERT_DIR=/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` (at least on this Ubuntu image). After changing that, `update-ca-certificates` correctly updates the certificate an all HTTPS requests are successful.

This should work now:

```
FROM rocker/r-base

# Add local certificate to Docker
ADD ./zscaler.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ZscalerRootCertificate-2048-SHA256.crt

# update certificates
RUN update-ca-certificates

# Try making https requests
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libssl-dev
CMD Rscript -e "install.packages('beepr')"
```